# It was the same deal that deposed president Viktor Yanukovych BACKED OUT OF in November - I don't understand that part in bold

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure

Source: http://mashable.com/2014/06/27/kiev-ukraine-european-union-deal/

> Ukrainians on Friday gathered in Kiev's Independence Square — the epicenter of the months-long clashes that ignited a revolution — after their newly elected president signed the long-awaited trade agreement with the European Union. It was the same deal that deposed president Viktor Yanukovych **backed out of** in November, leading to his ousting and bringing the prospect of war to Europe’s doorsteps.

I don't understand how that phrase in a bold font is connected, I don't even understand to what (or whom), to either their former president or the deal. This is very confusing.

Comment: "The same deal that [deposed president Viktor Yanukovych] [backed out of] in November" is a noun phrase. It's similar to "the book (that) he reads". It means that "He reads the book", and we are talking about "the book". "Which book?" "It's the book he reads."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[***Back out of*** (a deal)](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/back-out) is a phrase that means "to decide not to do something you agreed to do".

We can rearrange your sentence,

> *It was the same deal that deposed president Viktor Yanukovych **backed out of** in November, leading to his ousting and bringing the prospect of war to Europe’s doorsteps.*

into simple sentences (to make it easier to understand) like this:

> (Deposed) president Viktor Yanukovych backed out of the same deal in November.
>   <sup>(NOTE: *"The same deal"* has already been mentioned. It refers to *"the long-awaited trade agreement"*.)</sup>
>   Backing out of the deal led to his ousting and brought the prospect of war to Europe’s doorsteps.